# Jquerymobile links inside lists

Tags: jquery-mobile

With a jqmobile list, each of my items (in the **li** tag) points to a page, using a **a** tag, but I would like to put another **a** tag with a href mailto
The problem is it splits the item, without showing the mail link

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ca11111/ghxVY/

I would like to have the visual result of the first item, but with a clickable mail link as in the second item -> http://jsfiddle.net/ca11111/ghxVY/1/

Comment: What do you mean by it not displaying the mail link, the second half of the li (the blue circle) is a separate link which seems to work to me.

Comment: Yes but I would like to have the mail text written and visible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's possible by wrapping the `<a>` with another tag, ex `<p>` http://jsfiddle.net/ghxVY/6/